# cant upload images rails and error occur

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to upload an image to my localhost using gem 'carrierwave', i have painting and galleries controller  like below code

**painting controller**

```
class PaintingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @paintings=Painting.all
  end
  def new
    @painting=Painting.new
  end
  def show
    @painting=Painting.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    #byebug
    @painting=Painting.new(painting_params)
    if @painting.save
  flash[:success]="Created image in album"
  redirect_to gallery_path(@painting)
else
  flash[:error]="Fail!"
  render 'new'
end
  end

  private
  def painting_params
    params.require(:painting).permit(:name,:gallery_id)
  end
end
```

**Gallery controller**

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
@galleries=Gallery.all
  end

  def new
@gallery=Gallery.new
  end

  def show
@gallery=Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
@gallery=Gallery.create!(gallery_params)
redirect_to galleries_path
  end

  private
  def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

ok then 2 model files :
**gallery.rb**

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :paintings
end
```

**painting.rb**

```
class Painting < ApplicationRecord
  def access_params
      params.require(:painting).permit(:gallery_id, :name, :image)
    end

 belongs_to :gallery, optional: true
 mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

It seems everying goes well but then i stuck at the step showing image on show.html.erb in gallery.
**show.html.erb**

```
<div id="paintings">
  <% @gallery.paintings.each do |painting| %>
    <div class="painting">
      <%= image_tag painting.image_url.to_s %>
      <div class="name"><%= painting.name %></div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= link_to "edit", edit_painting_path(painting) %> |
        <%= link_to "remove", painting, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

the image isn't showed up althought flash in gallery 's controller reported that i created the image,i inspected the website then i tried print painting s'attributes on show.html.erb

```
<%= @gallery.name %>
<%= @gallery.paintings.name %>
<%= @gallery.paintings.gallery_id%>
<%= @gallery.paintings.image%>
```

Only gallery's name and painting's name are printed out. other two methods has an error occur.

```
undefined method `gallery_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I don't know why  gallery can only access to painting's name but not others two.I searched for this error but i dont think those situation apply to mine . What is the problem guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error ! in user controller add :image to method painting_params

```
def painting_params
    params.require(:painting).permit(:name,:gallery_id,:image)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "paintings" is a collection, not a single image, so you need to either iterate on each of them or select the first one:

```
<%= @gallery.paintings.first.name %>
<%= @gallery.paintings.first.gallery_id %>
<%= @gallery.paintings.first.image %>
```